# Installing Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS Issues on Dell Optiplex

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS from a USB however I am having issues.

Hardware:

- Dell Optiplex
- 160GB WD HD
- 6GB RAM
- Intel core 2 duo
- 64 bit

I had Ubuntu 12.0.4 installed until recently with no issues until I decided to format and update to 14.04.

I am following the official install documentation [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStickQuick) however still no success. Firstly I thought it was my 80gb hdd, so I got replacement 160gb one - same issue.

I am able to boot from the usb and go through the installer steps  (I create the bootable usb following the official docs [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)), choosing my country, language, enter name etc.. then when I click next to **install** it loads some files however I receive and error

```
...the following file did not match its source on the copy cd/dvd...
target/lib/modules/3.16.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/mtd/chips/cfi_cmdset_0001.ko
```

I have researched this and apparently it's related to a dodgy iso file, however I have downloaded both versions (64/32) from the official Ubuntu site, and other mirrors. Same error.

Other times when I re-try the install I won't receive the error at all, the screen will simply go black. No info at all, meaning I have to restart the process and try again.

Things I have tried so far;

- two hdds (80gb WD and 160gb WD)
- two usbs (2gb and 8gb)
- formatted boths hdds multiple times
- Ubuntu 14.04.2 (64bit)
- Ubuntu 14.04.2 (32bit)
- verified md5 hash was correct

The only thing I haven't tried in installing 12.04 again, I might try that now, although I don't see how it would make any difference?

From what I can see I am following all the steps, and I meet the hardware/software requirements. I would appreciate any advice or direction here as I am lost!

Comment: hardware issue, caused by adding extra RAM (faulty or wrongly installed?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issues was with the RAM. Initially I had 2GB installed but consequently installed an extra 4GB (making 6GB in total).

When I removed the extra 4GB it worked. Possibly it was faulty. All installed and working now.